How to give Prefilled Options in Meta Whatsapp API
I want to know how can we send some prefilled options in our Meta Whatsapp Template?
This is my template which contains of 1 RadioButtons and 2 Checkboxes, I made this using "flow" (survey_feedback_form) category on Meta Developers site.
This takes User choices , now when user wants to update the choice, rather than sending a new list, I want to send a list with all of the choices prefilled in this template.
Any ideas how can we achieve this ?
            { "messaging_product": "whatsapp", "to": number, "type": "template", "template": { "name": "user_assistance_messages", "language": { "code": "en_US" } }  
            }

